# Error Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function

Tags: javascript, eslint

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const token = req.headers.authorization;
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, 'somes');
    req.user = decoded.user;
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(401).json({
      message: 'Auth failed',
    });
  }
};
```

This is my **check-auth** middle ware I've configured AirBnB coding standards for this expressjs project.

I got an linting error. What does this really mean and how can I get rid of this error? Is it okay to put return statement in front of the next() function call like this `return next();` How does that affect to the code?

> error  Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function 
>   consistent-return

Comment: Have you tried adding return next();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's complaining that one of your code paths is returning a value, but the other isn't. Returning a value isn't necessary here.

Change

```
return res.status(401).json({
  message: 'Auth failed',
});
```

to

```
res.status(401).json({
  message: 'Auth failed',
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had my function that is inside the hook useSelector and I was using it together with the keys

```
   const petitions = useSelector((store) => {store.cachePetitions.results});
```

My solution only remove the keys and thus the error generated by eslint disappeared

```
const petitions = useSelector((store) => store.cachePetitions.results);
```